# Relation between matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Let $A=[a_{ij}]_{n×n}$ be a matrix over real numbers.Define a matrix $B=[\alpha^{i-j}a_{ij}]_{n×n}$. What is the relation between $A$ and $B$
I think the constant will come out with power $n$.
Please somebody help?

Comment: Take $A$ the matrix with every entry equal to $1$. Then $B=(\alpha^{i-j})$. How should be there a constant come out with power $n$ ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It means $A$ and $B$ are similar to each other. More specifically, $B=DAD^{-1}$, where $D=\operatorname{diag}(\alpha,\alpha^2,\ldots,\alpha^n)$.

Comment: But how did it occur to you that they are similar

Comment: @Upstart This is a quite common kind of similarity that pops up from time to time in linear algebra literature.

Comment: Ohh actually i was asked this question in an interview, and i was unable to answer.thnx for the answer